# Regex Format a hexadecimal

Tags: java, regex

I would like to know how to create a regex pattern in format of a hexadecimal.

The format should be: (0-9A-F)_16

I tried `[0-9A-F]_[0-9]`, but I am getting errors. Also, I do not believe the first part before the underscore works for multiple digits.

Example:

> FEDCBA987654321_16

Comment: I didn't understand your question , what is the input and what is the expected output ?

Comment: Hi. SO is not the "gimme code plz" kind of site. Show us what you tried and we might be able point out your mistakes.

Comment: Also, what do regexes have to do with formatting? Regex can match patterns in text, they don't format anything? Or did you mean "a regex that matches/finds a certain number format"?

Comment: Do you want to check if a number is a valid hexadecimal number? This expression would match all valid characters: `[0-9A-Fa-f]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
[0-9A-Fa-f]+_16
```

should work for this (`+` after a regex token means "match one or more repetitions of this token").

If you want to check whether a given string matches this pattern exactly, use

```
boolean foundMatch = subjectString.matches("[0-9A-Fa-f]+_16");
```

If you want to find the part of a longer string that matches your regex, you should add word boundaries around your regex:

```
String ResultString = null;
Pattern regex = Pattern.compile("\\b[0-9A-Fa-f]+_16\\b");
Matcher regexMatcher = regex.matcher(subjectString);
if (regexMatcher.find()) {
    ResultString = regexMatcher.group();
}
```

Comment: The answer above will only match strings ending with "_16". If you want to also match for example strings ending with "_8" or "_87" then you could put `_[0-9]{1,2}` (matches between 1 and 2 occurrences of digit). See http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/regex/quant.html for more about quantifiers. But do you really want to handle numbers in any base up to 99? I advise you to choose the bases you'll handle and then `_(?:2|4|8|10|16)` which matches base 2, 4, 8, 10 or 16.

Comment: If I wanted to limit the number of digits, how should I do that? I am talking about the base after the underscore. I want it to have at most 2 digits. I have worked out "[0-9A-F]+_[0-9]{1,2}+" but where should the plus sign be best placed?

Comment: No need for the plus sign if you use `{1,2}` which means "one to two occurrences". The plus sign means "at least one occurrence" and is really just a shortcut for `{1,}`

Comment: Thanks Andrew! One last thing, can you explain what "?:" of your answer means? I can't find it on the docs.